# MinGW/MSYS make error 2 and error 127

Tags: makefile, firefox-addon, mingw, gnu-make, msys

So I've spent a couple hours trying to google the solution to my problem, but I can't seem to find the answer...

I'm learning to make Firefox extensions and am following the directions here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Setting_Up_a_Development_Environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XUL%2FSchool_tutorial%2FSetting_Up_a_Development_Environment

Instead of using Cygwin, I downloaded MinGW and installed "mingw-developer-toolkit", "mingw32-base", and "msys-base". I unzip the HelloWorld2 file. I run msys.bat, navigate to src in HelloWorld2, and type make. This is my error. What's happening? How do I fix this?

```
Creating XPI file.
make: zip: Command not found
make: *** [../bin/xulschoolhello2.xpi] Error 127
```

I also tried doing the same thing through cmd.exe. I followed directions from [How to use GNU Make on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881854/how-to-use-gnu-make-on-windows) and
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

When I enter "make" from cmd, I get the following...

```
"Creating XPI file."
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, zip ../bin/xulschoolhello2.xpi install.rdf ch
rome.manifest content/browserOverlay.js content/browserOverlay.xul skin/browserO
verlay.css locale/en-US/browserOverlay.dtd locale/en-US/browserOverlay.propertie
s, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:76: recipe for target '../bin/xulschoolhello2.xpi' failed
make: *** [../bin/xulschoolhello2.xpi] Error 2
```

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and how I should fix it? I've spent many hours researching on google but could not find the answer. I really want to learn how to make firefox extensions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `make: zip: Command not found` is make saying that it tried to run `zip`, but that command was not found. Ensure `zip.exe` lies somewhere on your `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you bobbogo. After you found the problem for me and how to fix it, it took only a couple minutes to fix. I simply followed the directions below.

http://blog.fourthwoods.com/2013/01/04/managing-mingw-packages-with-mingw-get/

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what exactly have you done? I followed the link that you mentioned and installed msis-zip and msis-unzip, but still got the problem. What else should I do?

Comment: are you sure you installed the proper tools? they should be msys-zip and msys-unzip. Make sure you installed everything you're supposed to and use the msys.bat

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution. First checked you have zip program in your path variable. Then edit makefile for your zip program and change bin directory Exp.

```
# The zip application to be used.
ZIP := rar a

# The target location of the build and build files.
bin_dir := ..\bin
```

http://koti.mbnet.fi/jhu2/mozilla/XUL_School%20Hello%20World%202%20Mozilla%20tutorial.pdf