# running make in Powershell/CMD gives Error2

Tags: c, makefile

UPDATE: The tabulation error has been fixed.
so I am changing the scope of this issue to focus on error 2. I would like to keep this same post as there has been some valuable discussion.

I am attempting to run this Makefile on Windows, but it gives the error "missing separator". I did some googling, and it seems like this issue stems from having spaces instead of a tab. I opened up the file in notepad++ and it seems like all the tabs are placed correctly. Is there another syntax issue that would throw this error? It should be noted that this compiles perfectly fine on Ubuntu 18.04, therefore I am not entirely sure what the issue may be.

Code here:

```
#  where the executables should be installed:
BIN = $HOME/bin

# define your compiler here:
CC = gcc

# define your copy command here:
COPY = cp

# define your remove (or delete) command here:
RM = rm -f

# suffix of object files?  (o for unix, obj for MSDOS):
O = o

# suffix for executable files? (empty for unix, .exe for dos):
E =

# command line arguments for C compiler
WARN := \
 -Wall \
 -Wcast-align \
 -Wcast-qual \
 -Wmissing-declarations \
 -Wmissing-prototypes \
 -Wpointer-arith \
 -Wstrict-prototypes \
 -Wno-unused-parameter \
 -Wno-unused-function \
 -Wshadow \
 -Wundef \
 -Wwrite-strings
OPT1 = -DNDEBUG
#OPT2 = -O
CFLAGS = -g $(WARN) $(OPT1) $(OPT2)

#
# There should be no need to make changes below this line
#
TARGETS = abcml$(E) abcsim$(E) tabcfg$(E) mau2cfg$(E) cplcfg$(E) gnaw$(E) \
  wgtcfg$(E)

#make all targets
all : $(TARGETS)
    touch all

#target wgtcfg: Weight the configurations in a .cfg file
WGTCFG = wgtcfg.$(O) getcic.$(O) io.$(O) header.$(O) misc.$(O) zeroin.$(O)
wgtcfg$(E) : $(WGTCFG)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(WGTCFG) -lm

#target gnaw: subject an assemblage to attrition
GNAW = gnaw.$(O)  getcic.$(O) io.$(O) header.$(O) misc.$(O) zeroin.$(O) \
  unirand.$(O)
gnaw$(E) : $(GNAW)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(GNAW) -lm

#target cplcfg: Calculate complement of .cfg file
CPLCFG = cplcfg.$(O) getcic.$(O) io.$(O) header.$(O) misc.$(O) zeroin.$(O)
cplcfg$(E) : $(CPLCFG)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(CPLCFG) -lm

#target mau2cfg: convert .mau format to .cfg format
MAU2CFG = mau2cfg.$(O) getcic.$(O) misc.$(O) io.$(O) header.$(O) zeroin.$(O)
mau2cfg$(E) : $(MAU2CFG)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(MAU2CFG) -lm

#target abcsim: simulation program
ABCSIM = abcsim.$(O) getcic.$(O) zeroin.$(O) misc.$(O) io.$(O) unirand.$(O) \
  header.$(O)
abcsim$(E) : $(ABCSIM) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(ABCSIM) -lm

#target abcml: estimation program
ABCML = abcml.$(O) io.$(O) getcic.$(O) zeroin.$(O) misc.$(O) likelihood.$(O) \
  prlike.$(O) chol.$(O) amoeba.$(O)  symeig.$(O) unirand.$(O) header.$(O) \
  ninfomat.$(O)
abcml$(E) : $(ABCML) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(ABCML) -lm

#target tabcfg: tabulate configurations
TABCFG = tabcfg.$(O) getcic.$(O) misc.$(O) io.$(O) header.$(O) zeroin.$(O)
tabcfg$(E) : $(TABCFG) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(TABCFG) -lm

install : all
    $(COPY) $(TARGETS) $(BIN)

clean : 
    $(RM) *.$(O) *~ all bone junk* core abcmlsrc.zip try depend $(TARGETS)

abcmlsrc.zip :
    zip -l abcmlsrc LICENSE Makefile.dos Makefile.unix *.c *.h -x try.*

depend :
    echo '#Automatically generated dependency info' > depend
    $(CC) -M *.c >> depend

include depend
```

EDIT: Whew, ok, so fixing the error in the depend file leads to another wonderful error which can be pictured here below (The bit of mandarin states: 
"The system can not find the file specified"). Fixing the depend file now allows it to compile properly using WSL, but PowerShell is still not happy. Should I try to use a different compiler? My goal is to get the executable file from running make so I can do stuff with it.

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -DNDEBUG    -c -o wgtcfg.o wgtcfg.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -g -Wall -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wshadow -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -DNDEBUG -c -o wgtcfg.o wgtcfg.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): 系统找不到指定的文件。
make: *** [<builtin>: wgtcfg.o] Error 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message verbatim (it should reference the line number at which the error occurred).

Comment: @G.M. hopefully that suffices, it doesn't seem to give me the line for the error

Comment: It does: "depend:1". That means the error is on the first line in the `depend` file that you `include`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for pointing that out! I made an additional edit.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the comments?

Comment: Comment out the `include depend`. Then run `make depend` to generate a new dependency file.

Comment: I think that worked!

Comment: The quotes are in the `depend` file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That fixed the separator issue, but it appears to give Powershell a bunch more to complain about. However, WSL is happy and it compiles just fine

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes `"` in the `Makefile`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doing that yielded the same error it seems.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: regarding: `all : $(TARGETS)
    touch all`   This is not correct.  Suggest: '.PHONY: all` newline  `all: $(TARGETS)`

Comment: Apply my comment about: `all : $(TARGETS)` to `install` and `clean`

Comment: regarding the definition of: `WARN := \`   It is missing the main warnings:  `-Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: @user3629249 Assuming I implemented your code correctly, this did not work either unfortunately and threw the same error.

Comment: Well, it says it can't find gcc. Can you run e.g. `gcc --version` manually? Did you install gcc on Windows?

Comment: @melpomene I install it via this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows by using Vasantha's solution. Powershell says it didn't recognize gcc as a cmdlet.

Comment: @tadman I updated the post.

Comment: when writing macros, like: `RM = rm -f`  do not use '='  as that results in the macro being re-evaluated every time it is referenced.   Instead, use ':=' as the macro will only be evaluated once