# make command not working in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, github, makefile, command-prompt, gnu-make

I am trying to install a Github project named [oTranscribe](https://github.com/oTranscribe/oTranscribe) on my system, this is the first time I am installing any project from Github.

I followed the given process to install the project:-

1. Install Node.js and NPM
2. Run npm install to install dependencies
3. Run make build_prod to compile the dist folder.

I successfully completed the first two process, and installed make on the system and added the PATH variable as well. The problem comes when I try to run the last command i.e `make build_prod`; when I execute the command and press enter the command prompt does nothing and when I press enter twice it shows me the following error.

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\AUDICHYA>cd C:\xampp\htdocs\oTranscribe-master

C:\xampp\htdocs\oTranscribe-master>make build_prod dist

make compile_static
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/xampp/htdocs/oTranscribe-master'
# clear out existing dist folder
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, # clear out existing dist folder, ...) failed
.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [compile_static] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/xampp/htdocs/oTranscribe-master'
make: *** [build_prod] Error 2

C:\xampp\htdocs\oTranscribe-master>
```

Please let me know what should I do further?

Comment: The failure is related to the specifics of the project's makefile, which you have not presented.  Read the project's documentation carefully to determine how you are meant to perform the installation.  At a guess, however, you probably do not need to build the 'dist' target.  That name conventionally identifies a rule for building a distribution package (a source tarball, zip file, or similar).  The conventional name for a target that installs a package is "install".

Comment: The [`Makefile`](https://github.com/oTranscribe/oTranscribe/blob/master/Makefile) is written for a Unix-compatible system. Unless you have Cygwin or WSL or some other compatibility extension, this is unlikely to work on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, I had already mentioned that I have installed make, even after clarifying the question still this is marked for duplication.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions say that you should run

```
make build_prod
```

The makefile does not define the `dist`  target.