# How to fix 'make failedNo such file or directory' in cmder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cmder

Now I'm working on Ruby and rails on windows 10 and tried to install gems as like solargraph or rubocop on cmder but it is not working. It says 'make failedNo such file or directory'

ccmder says that

```
ERROR:  Error installing solargraph:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/ext/jaro_winkler
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190917-20996-6o1pbx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/ext/jaro_winkler
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.3/gem_make.out
```

I don't know why this happened...and installing other gems gives same error.

Comment: I have a friend who is stuck at the same points while it works perfectly with me. Did you finally solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue today. The key line is `make failedNo such file or directory - make`. This indicates that the installer is trying to use the program `make`, but it isn't installed. Since I'm on ubuntu, I just ran `sudo apt install make` and this solved the problem. Then `make` was installed and could be used without issue. For Windows, see [How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because when I had previously run `ridk install` I had selected only option 1 (`MSYS2 base installation`). The solution was to run `ridk install` again and select options 1 and 3 (`MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain`), which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

update using "gem update --system" should fix the issue

P.S. - If it don't solve the issue than try to update with specific version.

e.g. "gem update --system some_verison"

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work. Latest version already installed.