# When Set Up my PC in windows and Compiling Substrate, Git Cmd can not execute [make init] and [make build]

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Steps can be found at https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup

I got stuck at   CompilingSubstrate  /  Step2:Initialize your WebAssembly build environment

---

git CMD Output:

C:\Users.....>make init
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You will need to install `make` on your windows computer to support this command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows

Did you follow all the instructions for setting up Substrate on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to follow that guide on Windows.

1. Install visual studio 2020 (remember to select the c/c++ component during setup)
2. Install rustup
3. Run `rustup default nightly-2020-10-06 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown` (if you're on substrate-2.0.1 or later you don't need to specify 2020-10-06)
4. Install llvm
5. Under the node-template folder run `cargo r`
6. Done