# Substrate Dev Hub error when compile substrate-node-template in windows 10

Tags: substrate

I have followed the [instructions](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup) for setting up my windows based computer but when I try to initialize WebAssembly build environment from powershell with

```
make init
```

show this error:

```
./scripts/init.sh
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, env bash D:\Blockchain-substrate\substrate-node-template\scripts\init.sh, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:3: init] Error 2
```

The init.sh file contain

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

echo "*** Initializing WASM build environment ***"

if [ -z $CI_PROJECT_NAME ] ; then
    rustup update nightly
    rustup update stable
fi

rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly
```

The installed toolchains seems to be fine

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-2020-10-01-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-2021-03-15-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.52.0-nightly (107896c32 2021-03-15)
```

I have read everything that google could bring with my queries but no solved it, so I would appreciate your help

Comment: Did you try just running the individual commands on your machine? In general my guess is that the BASH script does not work on windows.

Comment: Of note: the devhub just got updated to use substrate v3 that deprecates the make file, and strongly suggests using WSL, not native windows, to develop: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/#1a-windows . Would you be willing to try it this way? We are able to  support much more quickly and easily if so

Comment: please start again with the node template v3.0.0 for best results while learning: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/v3.0.0

Comment: @NukeManDan thanks for your support, i will to install WSL to see what happens.

Comment: As @NukeManDan indicated, using WSL and the substrate node template V3, I already have the blockchain working. Thanks

Comment: I've already answered this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65489349/6819040

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Of note: the devhub just got updated to use substrate v3 that deprecates the make file, and strongly suggests using WSL, not native windows, to develop: substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/getting-started/#1a-windows .

This seems to be the best path for other windows users looking :)

Answer (score 0):

Substrate development for windows is not properly supported.
Powershell and Command Prompt always give errors, what you can do is install WSL, then install Ubuntu and access the WSL from Visual Studio Code itself.
Check out [this article](https://rahul-soshte47.medium.com/how-to-setup-your-windows-pc-for-substrate-development-9fe5abb48222) for detailed steps.