# Couldn't find make, how can I solve this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have this output:

make:

> The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
At line:1 char:1

+ make --directory=".output\"
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You don't have a suitable `make` command installed, which part of this is unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Another possibility is that it is not in the $path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing make is installed. You need to add to `$path` the location of make.

You can to this in settings/system properties/environment variables; you can do it in system variables or user's.

You can verify it is in your path with `Get-command make`.

If you're using the included WSL make (gmake for GNU/linux, typically  in order to build a GNU/Linux executable with gcc), you can create a link `make -> bash -c make` in one folder of your `$path`. You can check you have it in a powershell shell with `bash -c make`, if not, you need to install on of  the WSL distributions from the Store.

If you're building for Windows, you need to install it [How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)

In order to check which one you need, you want to open your file `Makefile`, and check which programs are invoked (gcc or something else).

Comment: How to check if I have installed make ?? and how to download it ?

Comment: I have installed minGw, and I have changed the path after installing the components, will the code be compiled on vs code after doing this ? or there is some other steps?

Comment: @MahmoudYasserHammam Restart vscode so it has an updated $path and then that's it.

Comment: make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: I have found this