# Installation of Rainflow algorithm for Octave

Tags: octave

I woud like to ask you a question regarding of installation of Rainflow package from this site: https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave

I should be this https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3026-rainflow-counting-algorithm modified Matlab package for Octave, but it does not work.
Installation is written here, but I am not able to do so. I am NOT a programmer, so I would like to ask you for help and detailed procedure of installation.

### Compilation and installation for GNU Octave

1. Do the following to create a compiled mex-file from "rainflow.c" and to test the result:
   `$ cd ./rainflow-octave$ make$ ls ./src/rainflow.mexrainflow.mex$ make test`
2. Move files: rainflow.mex, rainflow.m and sig2ext.m to a place where GNU Octave can find them.
   Octave will locate oct- or mex- files automatically if they are in a directory listed in the search path. To figure out the search path, do:
   `$ octaveoctave> path` Octave's search path contain the following directories:
   .
   /usr/local/share/octave/site-m
   Please do not hesitate to ask more questions if needed.

Best regards
Michal

## My system

- OS: e.g. **Windows 10
- Octave version: e.g. **Version 6.1.0**
- Installation method: e.g. **Downloaded" from https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to build and run the rainflow package just using Octave 6.2.0 on my Windows 10 system.

Octave is capable of performing some compilation internally in order to build packages. I have no idea how to use the rainflow tool once built, but the following process worked to create it:

1. download the rainflow source tree and unzip it to it's own folder. This is normally the purpose of the [`git`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) program mentioned above. It downloads and manages source code. Instead, manually download the source code.

- Start from [the rainflow page](https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave)
- click the Green button that says `Code`
- click Download ZIP, save the file in a folder named rainflow where you'll be able to find it again.  I used `C:\Octave\rainflow\`.

Now open Octave.  You can use the `pkg` tool to build an installable package from the downloaded source code and then install it. This package is simple enough that the Octave-Windows environment is sufficient to perform the build:

- in Octave, use either the `cd` command or the folder tree in the upper left of Octave  to navigate to the folder where you saved rainflow. In my case, using the `cd` command I would type `cd c:\octave\rainflow\`.  Yours might be different.
- the only file in that folder should be `rainflow-octave-master.zip`
- now, use the `pkg` tool to compile the package using the command `pkg build . rainflow-octave-master.zip` (the `.` means it will save the package in the current folder.)
- When it finishes there should now be a second file in that folder named `rainflow-1.0.2-x86_64-w64-mingw32-api-v55.tar.gz`
- install the package using the command `pkg install rainflow-1.0.2-x86_64-w64-mingw32-api-v55.tar.gz` (It will give some warnings about documentation, but the package should still install.)
- verify installation by listing installed packages using the command `pkg list`.  you should see rainflow in the list of packages. if not, try `pkg rebuild` then another `pkg list`.  In my case, I see partway down the list:

  ```
     rainflow  |   1.0.2 | C:\Users\USERNAME\octave\rainflow-1.0.2
  ```

You can now use the package by first loading it using the command `pkg load rainflow`.

Testing it out a bit:

```
octave:76> rainflow
error: rainflow: RAINFLOW requires at least one input argument.
octave:77> rainflow(1)
ans = [](3x0)
octave:78> A = magic(3)
A =

   8   1   6
   3   5   7
   4   9   2

octave:79> rainflow(A)
ans =

   0.5000   2.0000   0.5000   0.5000   3.5000
   3.5000   3.0000   8.5000   6.5000   5.5000
   1.0000   1.0000   0.5000   1.0000   0.5000
```

The only issue I see is that afterward `help rainflow` does not show the help from rainflow.m, I suspect it should be included in the rainflow.c file. maybe this has to do with a change in octave since rainflow was created? if you want to read the help, you need to navigate to the package installation location or the location of the source files you unzipped and type `help rainflow`, at which point it will show:

```
octave:49> help rainflow
'rainflow' is a script from the file C:\octave\rainflow\src\rainflow.m
 RAINFLOW cycle counting.
   RAINFLOW counting function allows you to extract
   cycle from random loading.

 SYNTAX
   rf = RAINFLOW(ext)
   rf = RAINFLOW(ext, dt)
   rf = RAINFLOW(ext, extt)

 OUTPUT
   rf - rainflow cycles: matrix 3xn or 5xn dependend on input,
     rf(1,:) Cycles amplitude,
     rf(2,:) Cycles mean value,
     rf(3,:) Number of cycles (0.5 or 1.0),
     rf(4,:) Begining time (when input includes dt or extt data),
     rf(5,:) Cycle period (when input includes dt or extt data),

 INPUT
   ext  - signal points, vector nx1, ONLY TURNING POINTS!,
   dt   - sampling time, positive number, when the turning points
          spaced equally,
   extt - signal time, vector nx1, exact time of occurrence of turning points.


   See also SIG2EXT, RFHIST, RFMATRIX, RFPDF3D.
```

those other functions appear to be included as well and the help works, so you can try `help sig2ext`, `help rfhist`, `help rfmatrix`, and `help rfpdf3d`.  I have not tested to see if they all actually work.  But this will get the package up and running for you to start using.  Good luck!

Comment: surely this implies mingw is preinstalled and placed in the path though, right?

Comment: no.  the windows build includes things like that embedded within octave. (on windows you can't assume anything is installed or even available outside of the OS itself.  yay windows.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I'm on linux, but process should be the same on windows.

```
mkdir TempFolder
cd TempFolder
git clone https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave.git
cd rainflow-octave
make      # for some reason this places the .tar.gz package in the PARENT folder
cd ..     # so let's go there
octave    # and let's start octave from this directory
```

now from inside octave:

```
pkg prefix /path/where/you/want/the/package/to/be/installed
pkg install rainflow-octave-1.0.2.tar.gz
pkg load rainflow   # to load the package and test it
rfctest   # run the test to ensure it works
```

Comment: replace windows equivalent commands as appropriate ( e.g. I think 'mkdir' on windows is 'md', etc )

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunatelly I am not a programmer, so I stucked at command "git clone https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave.git". I tried command make but it gave an answer: 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Hi @AaaA, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows

Comment: @AaaA don't give up hope!  see my answer below. I tried to give step by step instructions for you to get it installed on windows using nothing other than Octave and the downloaded source code.