# Instalation Octave package / I cant perform "make" command

Tags: command, octave

I woud like to ask you a question regarding of installation of Rainflow package from this site: https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave but I cant perform "make"command. Please look at the picture Command line below.

I am NOT a programmer, so I would like to ask you for help and detailed procedure of installation.

Compilation and installation for GNU Octave
Do the following to create a compiled mex-file from "rainflow.c" and to test the result: $ cd ./rainflow-octave$ make$ ls ./src/rainflow.mexrainflow.mex$ make test
Move files: rainflow.mex, rainflow.m and sig2ext.m to a place where GNU Octave can find them. Octave will locate oct- or mex- files automatically if they are in a directory listed in the search path. To figure out the search path, do: $ octaveoctave> path Octave's search path contain the following directories: . /usr/local/share/octave/site-m Please do not hesitate to ask more questions if needed.
Best regards Michal

[Command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlJcL.png)

Comment: The Makefile is for Linux. But there is a README file that explains the steps that you need to do, you can do these manually: https://github.com/AmritaLonkar/rainflow-octave/blob/master/doc/README.octave

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate questions: [Installation of Rainflow algorithm for Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391979/installation-of-rainflow-algorithm-for-octave)

Comment: IT does not work, I cant perform this command: mkoctfile --mex --strip rainflow.c

Comment: You need to install development tools (most likely MSVC). And you need to have `mkoctfile` on your path. Maybe you can run that command from within Octave?

Comment: you should specify in the question that you're running Windows and trying compile a package, and you don't currently have a computer set up for compiling code.  Then people could help you determine if it is possible to set up your windows PC to do the installation, or if the Octave pkg manager can do the installation within the program.

Comment: are you running the mkoctfile command within Octave and not at the Windows command prompt?