# How to solve make × ERR not found: make-$(SOURCE_FILES) while running npm run build command

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-start

I am trying to run command `npm run build`. I am getting error

```
`make i info Invoking build target
make i info Invoking dist/build target
(node:15892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15892) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
make × ERR  not found: make-$(SOURCE_FILES)`
```

Please anyone can help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it installing `make` command using chocolaty in my window. I was getting error because `make` was not installed on my windows (I had no idea regarding that make is window's command not NodeJs').

This post helped me to solve my problem.

[How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)