# How to install Python package LIBPMF from makefile?

Tags: python, makefile, package

I would like to install package LIBPMF whose official website is [https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~rofuyu/libpmf/](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Erofuyu/libpmf/). The complete file of this package can be downloaded from [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Erofuyu/libpmf/libpmf-1.42.tgz). After unzip, we have

[image]

Inside folder `python`, we have

[image]

Inside `README`, we have

```
Requirement
===========
    - numpy
    - scipy.sparse

Build
=====
    type `make' in this directory


A Simple Example
================
    Within the directoy python/, open a python shell.

    >>> import libpmf
    >>> import scipy.sparse as sparse
    >>> A = sparse.rand(100,100,0.3)
    >>> model = libpmf.train(A, '-k 10 -l 0.1')
    starts!
    m 100 n 100 k 10 nnz 3000
    Wall-time: 0.0212269 secs
    >>> model.keys() # model is a dictionary
    ['H', 'W']
```

My OS is `Windows 10 Pro version 21H2 build 19044.1348` and my Anaconda is `Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64`.

I could not understand the instruction `type "make" in this directory`. Could you please elaborate on how to install the package in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal in the directory where you unzipped. You have to type then in the terminal 'make'. I think this will not work, because you need a linux system. Do do that on windows, look at this link:

[makefile in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)