# Invoking `awk` in a makefile recipe

Tags: awk, makefile, gnu-make, git-bash

I have a makefile with a phony target in it. When run, this target makes sure that a shell script in the same directory has the correct permissions and Unix-style line endings instead of Windows-style, then runs the script.

Previously, I had been using [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) for the line ending conversions, but after discovering this was not part of POSIX (see list of POSIX utilities [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html)), I tried using `awk` instead.

I had tested:

`awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' $FILENAME`

by running it directly on the command line (I took it from an answer that was [posted to both *Unix & Linux*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153091/how-to-add-a-carriage-return-before-every-newline/296534#296534) and [to Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/156516/is-there-a-bash-command-to-convert-r-n-to-n/1066353#1066353)). It also didn't have any single `$` signs to replace with `$$` in the makefile recipe.

But when I added it to the recipe,

```
revert_source:
    awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' ./revert_source.sh
    @chmod u+x ./revert_source.sh
    @./revert_source.sh
```

```
$ make revert_source
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' ./revert_source.sh
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN blocks must have an action part
make: *** [makefile:258: revert_source] Error 1

$ make -d revert_source | grep -n "awk"
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN blocks must have an action part
make: *** [makefile:258: revert_source] Error 1
50375:CreateProcess(C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\awk.exe,awk BEGIN{RS=\"\1\";ORS=\"\";getline;gsub(\"\r\",\"\");print>ARGV[1]} ./revert_source.sh,...)
```

I've tried adding backslashes as escape characters before the `{` and `}`, replacing single backslashes with double backslashes, and still I can't get this to work.

I have replaced the `awk` command with a `tr` command, but this needs to create a temporary file and then use additional lines of code to replace the original file's contents with those of the temporary. So it's a step backwards in terms of code quality, and I would like to get the `awk` command to work properly.

Comment: Is it actually important that `dos2unix` is not a standard POSIX utility?  It is widely available, and one option would be simply to make it a dependency of your project.

Comment: It looks like you are running this on Windows.  In your environment, is `make` using a POSIX shell to execute the recipe?  If it is using PowerShell or cmd.exe then there are likely to be problems associated with specifying the awk script on the command line.  You could probably work around that by putting the script in a file.  (But maybe that would produce a chicken-and-egg problem.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know what sort of environment our customers might be running this in. If we take Cygwin as an example, then I'm pretty sure that dos2unix isn't included in a Cygwin install by default, and searching Cygwin's packages for that name will get you nowhere. There IS a Cygwin package you can install that contains it, but that package has a completely different name. Something like textutils or tofrodos, IIRC. I've also been stung by unexpected compatibility issues before, so aiming for POSIX-compliance was an attempt to pre-emptively avoid any such.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would expect that something like Git Bash, Cygwin, or msys2 in one of its various forms would be the most likely shell for this to be run from. WSL is also possible, as is an actual Unix/Linux. I don't expect it to be run from `cmd` or PowerShell.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my question about shells.  To clarify: **it looks like `make` may be using something other than a POSIX shell to run your `awk` command**.  This is something that sometimes happens on Windows, where the most common alternatives used are `cmd.exe` and `PowerShell`.  I was not asking for a prediction of others' usage, but rather suggesting that you check what was happening in your own test.

Comment: I'm using Git Bash to run it. If it runs OK in there, I retest on Cygwin and then the msys variants. The failure in my post is happening in Git Bash. I did test the `awk` command by using it directly from there, and it worked, so I think my problem is that there's something I need to do (maybe escaping something) to turn it into part of a makefile recipe.

Comment: Again, not responsive to my question.  I'm not talking about which shell you use to run `make`.  I am asking about what shell `make` uses to run recipes.  These frequently are different, though it's mostly on Windows where there's a risk that the shell used by `make` is not a Bourne-compatible shell.  And I ask this because your Makefile itself looks fine and works for me on Linux.

Comment: Ah. In that case, the value of `$(SHELL)` is `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe`. I didn't explicitly set it, it just defaults to that when the makefile is run in Git Bash. Changing it to `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe` does not resolve my problem.

Comment: Ok then, this is very mysterious.  You could try better simulating what `make` is doing by running `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe -c 'awk '\''BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}'\'' ./revert_source.sh'`. (I recommend cutting&pasting that, btw, as the quoting is a bit gnarly and open to misreading.)

Comment: After copy-pasting the above, and using a backslash to escape the space in "Program Files", the command succeeds, just as it did when run directly from the shell.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  What about the output of `type -p awk`?

Comment: `type -p awk` and `command -v awk` both output `/usr/bin/awk` when run directly in shell. In a makefile recipe, `echo $$(type -p awk)` also outputs this. But just putting `type -p awk` in the recipe leads to: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, type -p awk, ...) failed.` 
`make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.` 
`make: *** [makefile:193: build/H753GCC_Default.out] Error 2`. Though I suspect that's because the `-p` option to `type` is not part of POSIX.

Comment: I no longer suspect that the `CreateProcess` failure was related to `-p` not being one of `type`'s POSIX options. This is because: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, type awk, ...) failed.` Which must be something to do with `type` being a shell builtin, not a program.

Comment: There may be more than one issue at play here. If I escape the braces (`{` and `}`) I get a different error: `awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{RS=\\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]\} ./revert_source.sh`
 `awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ backslash not last character on line`. I can work around all this by not escaping the braces, and instead using `$$( ... )` in the makefile to run `awk` in a subshell.

Comment: The symptoms look like `make` ends up running `cmd` after all. The legacy command interpreter from DOS is notoriously finicky with quoting, to the point where the usual recommendation is to save your Awk script in a file and run it with `awk -f`

Comment: @tripleee After some intial scepticism, I looked more closely at the version of make I was using. After discovering that it was mingw32-make, I found [this mailing list post](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/36939273/), which stated: *"mingw32-make is the CMD-based GNU make variant, which understands batch syntax rather than shell syntax."* I'm surprised, especially as so far it's seemed to be using shell instead of batch syntax in the recipes, but from the sound of it you're probably right.

Comment: Luckily, `awk` without a subshell did not cause problem's for Cygwin's make.

Comment: Not so luckily, Chocolatey's make has the same problems as mingw32-make. In fact, for all I know it might BE mingw32-make!

Comment: Fortunately, it's not hard to find a proper `make`. But then come to think of it, it's not hard to find a proper operating system.

Comment: Unless your employer requires you to use Windows. Or if you don't know which OS and which version of `make` your customers will be using. So I need to try to "code defensively" when writing the makefile.