# How to use "make" with Windows and Anaconda?

Tags: windows, makefile, anaconda, cookiecutter

I am attempting to follow [this](https://github.com/hackalog/bus_number#readme) tutorial to learn how to use the Cookiecutter folder structure for data science projects. My machine is running Windows 10 and I am using Anaconda.

It seems that the Cookiecutter project structure relies heavily on Makefiles, as does the above tutorial I am trying to follow.

Is there a way to use `make` on Windows and while using Anaconda?

What I've tried....

The first step is to check my installations. I open Anaconda command prompt and run each of the following.

```
conda --version
make --version
git --version
cookiecutter --version
```

When I run `make --version` I get the following error. `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

When I attept to install `make` by running `conda install -c anaconda make`, I get:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - make
```

Looking at the Anaconda `make` documentation [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/make), I see it is not available for Windows.

More searching led me to `m2w64-make`, with documentation found [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/m2w64-make).

I open an Anaconda command window and install the package using `conda install -c conda-forge m2w64-make`. Installation appears to run with no errors.

However when I attempt to run this package, nothing happens.

When I run `m2w64-make --version` I get:

```
'm2w64-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I run `make --version` I get:

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows) Stack Overflow post appears to be very similar at first, but all of the answers tell the OP to use Chocolatey, and do not give an option for Anaconda.

Comment: Installing software is only the first step in allowing it to be invoked.  The second step is adding the directory containing the software to your `PATH` so that the system can find it.  You'll have to find out what directory Anaconda installed GNU make into, and ensure that directory is on your `PATH`.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you for your answer. Anaconda installed it into the same directory it installs all packages: `.\Anaconda3\pkgs\`. I've installed many other packages this way and have never had this problem before.

Comment: Note, I'm talking about where it put the actual make program.  It will be called something like `m2w64-make.exe`  Is that command in that directory?  is that directory on your `PATH`?  I don't know anything about Anaconda but it seems mostly for installing Python packages; these are not programs like make, so just because it can run installed Python packages doesn't mean it can run stand-alone packages like `make`.

Comment: If the Anaconda install doesn't want to work, I would still try https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/make. For most imaginable makefiles in Anaconda it should make no difference and I found this to work acceptably well, unless you try to do C or C++ development Unix style, where the rough edges and holes start to break down the normal development approach.

Answer (score 0):

Running `mingw32-make --version` works.