# Downloading auxiliary data with anaconda prompt

Tags: python, windows, makefile, anaconda

I'm following the steps [here](https://github.com/murat-savci/PACG/tree/main). So I used the following code to install dependencies,

```
  conda create -n polymer -c conda-forge mamba
  conda activate polymer
  mamba env update -f environment.yml
```

But in the next step, I couldn't download auxiliary data by,

```
make auxdata_all
```

Edit:

As suggested by @Musabbir Arrafi, I first installed make package and cd into the folder which ther is makefile in it. Then after uaing make auxdata_all command I get this error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
make: ***[makefile:68: directories] Error 1
```

I searches a lot for this exact error but with no result. Can you help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [makefile](https://github.com/murat-savci/PACG/blob/799f4155a6182b768f261831aa9bbefdac47fd3f/makefile) of the [project](https://github.com/murat-savci/PACG/tree/main) you're interested in is written for [POSIX-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell. But the error you're experiencing indicates that you're on Windows, right? If so, then here's what happened.

When you execute `conda install -c anaconda make`, the [GNU Make](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/make) is installed, which in turn uses [COMSPEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSPEC) by default when [choosing a shell in MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) to run commands. Usually `COMSPEC` is equal to something like `C:WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`.

Now, when `cmd.exe` is trying to execute `mkdir -p auxdata/common/` (the first action of the *directories* target in the *makefile*), you encounter the error *"The syntax of the command is incorrect"*. This error occurs because `cmd.exe` requires the path with the backslash as a separator, sort of `auxdata\common\` instead of `auxdata/common/` (also keep in mind, that `cmd.exe` doesn't know any parameters in [mkdir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir) and is gonna treat `-p` as a name of a directory to create, which in itself is a silent problem).

To run `make` smoothly, you may need to install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/). For further guidance, check the answers to [How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32127524/14909621)

Answer (score 1):

The correct steps are these:

- First install `make` from your anaconda prompt, if you don't have it installed already

```
conda install -c anaconda make
```

- Then install your dependencies

```
conda create -n polymer -c conda-forge mamba
conda activate polymer
mamba env update -f environment.yml
```

- then `make`

```
make auxdata_all
```

You don't need to put `$` before the command, the `$` is a special character in shell script, you don't have to put that yourself.

Comment: Thanks! But this gives me ```'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: you need to install make in your conda prompt, follow this: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/make

Comment: I've added how you can install make in the answer. Let me know if you face anymore problems!

Comment: Actually I faced a problem in installing make but managed to fix. But after running ```make auxdata_all``` It says ```make: *** No rule to make target 'auxdata_all'.  Stop.```

Comment: Check if you're in the correct directory to where you installed your dependencies

Comment: Sorry still couldn't fix.

Comment: Hello, I tried installing the package on other PC I could manage to download make. Then I cd to Polymer file directory and wrote "make auxdata_all" but it gives this error: The syntax of the command is incprrect. make: **[makefile: 66: directories] Error1

Comment: It seems to be an error with the makefile now

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi No, the `makefile` is okey, The problem is in the default command interpreter which is `cmd.exe` in case of MS Windows.

Comment: You're probably right. Not much of a windows user here