# Why can't I use make in VS Code terminal?

Tags: c, windows

Brand new to programming. Following a tutorial on C, where the creator uses these 3 commands in the terminal:

```
code hello.c

make hello

./hello
```

The `make hello` command doesn't work on my end for some reason. Giving me this error instead:

```
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

```
make hello
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

EDIT: I managed to get through the first error. I didn't have make installed, and now I have this error:

```
cc     hello.c   -o hello
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc hello.c -o hello, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 2
```

I tried looking this up online, but since I just got started I have no idea what any of this means.
I was expecting the command to work.

Comment: did you install `make`? If you installed then did you add it to the `PATH` environment variable? If yes then did you restart the shell to use the new environment variable

Comment: Related: [using-make-from-windows-powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/808807/using-make-from-windows-powershell)

Comment: @phuclv I installed make. I've tried now adding it to the PATH environment variable. Never heard of that before so I don't know if I actually did it correctly. Got the same error regardless

Comment: Is this your tutorial? https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2024/notes/1/#:~:text=The%20first%20command%2C%20code%20hello,runs%20the%20program%20called%20hello%20.

Comment: @nostromo yes, that's the one.

Comment: @Klaus what did you add? Did you restart the shell? Run `Get-Command make` and see. Show everything you tried

Comment: @phuclv I installed make, because I didn't have it. I got a different error now: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc hello.c -o hello, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 2`.
I reloaded VScode, ran `Get-Command make` and got ```CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     make.exe                                           1.0.0.0    C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\make.exe```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using PowerShell on VS Code terminal. I am very familiar with the error.

Install make because it is not installed.

Check out this link I found on this platform: [How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)

Comment: I downloaded it from Make for Windows. Still got the same error.

Comment: I just tried to install make on my test windows VM using Chocolatey and it worked.
I wish I could attach the result here.

First, you must run PowerShell as Administrator.

Install Chocolatey: https://community.chocolatey.org/courses/installation/installing?method=install-from-powershell-v3

Afterwards, you Install make with the command "choco install make"

Comment: I got it now, but now I got a different error.
"process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc hello.c -o hello, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 2"

Comment: Great! So, on VS Code just install the c extension.

You can use: C/C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft

Comment: I already have it installed, still getting that error.