# How do I use GMake on Windows

Tags: dll, build, gnu-make, tbb

I've downloaded the source files for the TBB libraries, with the intent to build them and link them into my CMake project. The readme file says "type 'gmake' in this directory to build and test."

My question is - how do I run gmake on a Windows machine.
The solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881854/how-to-use-gnu-make-on-windows) answer didn't work for me. This is what I get:

[image: Errors]

Comment: What about that solution didn't work? The executable will likely just be `make` and not `gmake` on many/most systems. Are there perhaps more Windows-friendly build instructions available?

Comment: How are the title, your question, the tags you have chosen and StackOverflow related? CMake is not part of your question, your problem is unrelated to programming, it's just you are not able to build a library! Downvoting.

Comment: Yes sorry, edited.

Answer (score 2):

From the log I see that make unable to find Microsoft compiler cl.exe. To fix this, you must use one of the "Visual Studio command prompt"-s, those are cmd with environments targeted to command-line tools.

If you use MigGW by chance, the command should be
`make compiler=gcc`.
In this case, path environment variable should contain path to MigGW.